# Resubscribe to hot observable unless it completes, then cache for limited time

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, observable

I have another problem which I encounter often, but can't wrap my head around and solve using rxJava.

I have a long running operation (an observable). What I want to achieve is an observable that:

- with the first subscription, starts the long operation
- subsequent subscribers attach to the observable (if it hasn't completed yet)

These two are solvable using `share`, but there are two more requirements:

- when all the subscribers unsubscribe, the next subscribers should still attach to already long running operation (unless it's completed). This is where `share` fails me
- when the long operation completes, its result is cached for some time. New observers should immediately get `completed` notification. After specified time everything *resets*, back to square one

For now my long running operation is wrapped in an observable, and all I could achieve is three first points: multiple subscribers share the subscription, which runs even if all of the subscribers unsubscribe, and it's restarted when it completes and someone subscribes again. However, I still can't get it to cache the result, so that for 100 ms after the observable completes, all new subscribers immediately receive `onCompleted` callback:

```
private Observable<Integer> createObservable() {
    Observable<Integer> values = Observable.merge(
            Observable.just(10),
            Observable.just(50).delay(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
            Observable.just(100).delay(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));

    return Observable.defer(() -> values)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .publish()
        .autoConnect()
        .doOnCompleted(() ->
                Observable.timer(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .doOnCompleted(() -> this.observable = createObservable())
                        .subscribe());
}
```

I'd appreciate any hint

Answer (score 3):

For caching I would save results to memory with a time stamp. Then use `concat` for getting results from cache while time stamp still valid. Example:

```
public static class WrappedResult {
    private final String value;
    private final long time;

    public WrappedResult(String value, long time) {
        this.value = value;
        this.time = time;
    }
}

private Observable<WrappedResult>  getLongRunningObservable() {
    return Observable.just("1")
            .map(s -> new WrappedResult(s, System.currentTimeMillis()))
            //save result to cache
            .doOnNext(pair -> mCache = pair);
}

private Observable<WrappedResult> getCachedResult() {
    return Observable.just(mCache);
}

public Observable<String> getObservable() {
    return Observable.concat(getCachedResult(), getLongRunningObservable())
            //use cache if it's not too old. otherwise perform long running operation again
            .first(wrappedResult -> System.currentTimeMillis() - wrappedResult.time <= TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(100))
            .map(wrappedResult -> wrappedResult.value)
            //continue with your implementation for ConnectableObservable
            ;
}
```

More info about [Loading data from multiple sources with RxJava](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/06/22/loading-data-from-multiple-sources-with-rxjava/)

Comment: Thanks, this is valid approach that I considered, but was looking for pure rx solution (without manual caching) - I was under impression that some `retry`, `retryWhen`, `cache` or other operator would be able to do exactly what you just wrote. So I'll wait a bit before accepting this as an answer, although it's probably a valid solution

Answer (score 0):

Untested, and it might run the loop forever, so buyer beware:

```
Observable.switchOnNext(
   defer(()-> ...)
   .cache() // or .share() if you don't mind about losing initial entries
   .concatMap(Observable.empty().delay(timeout));
```

This observable will never emit `onCompleted`, as I assumed by the description that was desired. If instead you want the observable to complete, then something more complex is needed - use onCompleted() to mark the time of last completion and use that in defer() to determine whether a new observable is needed or if the old one is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for answer, however this is not quite what I meant. _New observers should immediately get `completed` notification_, so I actually need completed called too. Also I don't quite get it how it would lazily start hot observable and keep it running when everyone unsubscribes (if I use `share()`)